# I am getting a file not found undefined Error in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-not-found, domexception

Hello I am creating a game similar to Simon. Where a user has to memorize a random color generated by the random color generator. When a button is clicked it is supposed to play a sound. I am able to play all the sounds when I click the buttons. I created a function that recognizes when the enter key is pressed to start the game. The game generates a random color with a corresponding sound and the user is supposed to click the same color. I am getting a **ERROR NOT FOUND sounds/undefined.mp3 and also a DOM Exception: no supported source was found**. It seems not to be able to find the right file. [image]

```js
function nextSequence() {

  level = level + 1;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 4);
  randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
  console.log(gamePattern);


  //$("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  animatePress(randomChosenColor);

  playSound(randomChosenColor);
  // animatePress(randomChosenColor);
}

$(".btn").click(function() {

    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
    console.log(userClickedPattern);
    playSound(userChosenColor);
    animatePress(userChosenColor);

});

function playSound(variable) {

  $("#" + variable).ready(function() {

    var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + variable + ".mp3");
    audio.play();
  });

}


$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {

   if(e.which == 13) {

      var h1header = document.getElementById("level-started").innerHTML = "Level " + level;
      nextSequence();
      started = true;
  

   }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 3rem;

}

body {

  text-align: center;
}


.container {

    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 6%;
  margin: 25px;

}

.red {

  background-color: red;
}

.blue {

  background-color: blue;
}

.green {

  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {

  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {

  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon Game</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="intro" id = "level-started">Press Enter Key to start </h1>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="btn green"  type="button" id="green">

      </div>
      <div class="btn red"  type="button" id="red">

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="btn yellow"  type="button" id="yellow">

      </div>

      <div class="btn blue"  type="button" id="blue">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">

  </script>
</body>

<footer>&copy Hello World </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with `randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];`. What do you see if you do `console.log(randomChosenColor)`?

Comment: I am getting undefined when I log the randomChosenColor.

Comment: You put that in the `nextSequence` function, right? Then the problem is with the `buttonColors` array, which you haven't shown in the code.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It couldn't find the file because the number randomizer was written incorrectly. I was missing the brackets making it a function. What i had = randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 4).    The Math.random() needed parentheses.